# How to check the subclass of an object and return the correct type in a method?

Tags: java, generics

I have a list of Objects that I know have subclasses. I want to create a function where you pass the Object type and it returns the subclass. How would I do this? The problem I am having is the return type. You can only have 1 return type so I can't think of a way to do this.

```
public returnType getSubclassObject(Object someObject){
    if(someObject instanceof com.example.stuff.ObjectOne){
       return (ObjectOne)someObject;
    } else if(someObject instanceof com.example.stuff.ObjectTwo){
       return (ObjectTwo)someObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to have a return type which depends on the "inside" of the method. How do you want to use the `ObjectOne` and `ObjectTwo` types when they are returned?

Comment: How would you like to use such method? What type would you use to store its result?

Comment: Good point, I never thought about how to store the result. I guess I'll just do everything in that method.

Comment: BTW `instanceof` operator often indicates that you should rethink your classes structure. So instead of using this operator to chose how to treat your instance consider making each of your `ObjectOne` and `ObjectTwo` classes implement `SomeInterface` (which will have `someMethod()`). Now simply provide unique code for each these classes. After that you can create method which will accept instances of `SomeInterface` and invoke `someMethod()` on each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return different types by the same method in java except if they are children of the parent defined one.

But, you can try to use a *strategy pattern*. It's helpful in your case: You can use an *Interface* which is implemented by both *ObjectOne* and *ObjectTwo*. And define a method getSubClassObject that do the work for each kind of object, instead of casting objects.